# How to build a custom chatbot with custom voice?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, voice-recognition, chatbot

Basically I wanted to build a chatbot with voice. But I wanted the voice to be custom. I checked over the link:
https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-build-your-own-ai-assistant-using-api-ai/
https://dialogflow.com/
The above links say how to build a chatbot but it does not tell about the necessary programming required for a custom voice.

Even if a custom voice is not possible when using other API for chatbot, how to create a chatbot API of our own?

To start with, I have a basic requirement like:
If I say hello, the chatbot should respond using voice "hello" but in the voice that I configure. (I would record it previously and store it in a file and it should play that file)

How to configure this "voice" or "sound" portion of it?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to store every response in a file then why do u need a chat bot. Simply use if else condition. If output is hello then points it towards that file name.
Still i dont know what u want to achieve with it.